# CarouselView in .Net MAUI: CurrentItem and Position do not work

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, maui

I noticed that CarouselView in my .Net MAUI solution does not react on Position or CurrentItem change. Then I took "Maui samples" solution (https://github.com/dotnet/maui-samples) and reproduced the same on "Set CurrentItem/Position" sample page. This is sample solution code, I did not change a single line of code, ran "as is"

```
        public MonkeysViewModel()
        {
            source = new List<Monkey>();
            CreateMonkeyCollection();

            CurrentItem = Monkeys.Skip(3).FirstOrDefault();
            OnPropertyChanged("CurrentItem");
            Position = 3;
            OnPropertyChanged("Position");
        }
```

It's supposed to skip first 3 items and display 4th monkey, but instead it displays the very first which is Baboon:

[image]

I use Android Emulator API 32. Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Oh that's nothing, Try using PeekInsets and see what happens :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some relative issue about this problem.

You can follow them up here:

https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/7575

https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/9749

Thanks for your support and feedback.

Best Regards!

Jessie